# Blackberry - How to grey out menu items?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, menu

I want to grey out some menu items, so thay will be visible but disabled.
How to do this in blackberry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paradigm for the BlackBerry menu is to remove inactive menu items, not grey them out.  So, there is no functionality that allows greying out.