# how to visually disable MenuItems in ActionMode

Tags: android, menuitem, android-menu, android-actionmode

In my `ActionMode` I disable and enable the `MenuItems` of a `CAB` depending on some conditions like:

```
        if (isConditionMet)) {
        MenuItem[] fileActionsToLock = { mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_share),
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_rename),
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_copy),
                mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_move) };
        for (MenuItem i : fileActionsToLock) {
            i.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

I would like to also disable those `CAB` `MenuItems` ***visually***, e.g. something like changing the alpha value of their `CAB` icons. Is there any way to do this without actually replacing the icons by calling `setIcon()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642990/is-it-possible-to-grey-out-not-just-disable-a-menuitem-in-android This question seems to have a few solutions.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I already figured out a simple way to do this (thus own answer)

Comment: haha yea, thus the upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

never mind, I just figured out to use `mMenuItem.getIcon().setAlpha(xxx);` This will actually work for any kind of `Menu` (I guess).